# can't start solana validator node

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-18.04, solana

hello i'm currently trying to start a validator node on a server , following the documentation i made the system file as shown

```
[Unit]
Description=Solana Validator
After=network.target
Wants=solana-sys-tuner.service
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=cmfirpc1
LimitNOFILE=1000000
#LogRateLimitIntervalSec=0
Environment="PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/home/cmfirpc1/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin"
ExecStart=/home/cmfirpc1/bin/validator.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and created a validator.sh file like shown bellow ,

```
#!/bin/bash exec solana-validator \
 --identity ~/validator-keypair.json \ 
--vote-account ~/vote-account-keypair.json \
 --rpc-port 8899 \
 --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
 --limit-ledger-size \ --log ~/solana-validator.log
```

and execute chmod+x on validtor.sh.
however i get the error ,

```
● sol.service - Solana Validator
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sol.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-12-03 23:40:44 UTC; 375ms ago
Process: 263114 ExecStart=/home/cmfirpc1/bin/validator.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
Main PID: 263114 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

Comment: Insert a line break after `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: i didn't ,same issue

Comment: So does runing `/home/cmfirpc1/bin/validator.sh` from terminal works?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing a new line. The `#` results in the `exec`-command being interpreted as part of the command.

```
#!/bin/bash 
exec solana-validator \
 --identity ~/validator-keypair.json \ 
 --vote-account ~/vote-account-keypair.json \
 --rpc-port 8899 \
 --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
 --limit-ledger-size \ --log ~/solana-validator.log
```